# RecyclerView Without Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Stupid question, this is my situation:

`MainActivity`

`Fragment1` with `RecyclerView` (In the activity I retrive data from db, set the adapter and pass it to `RecyclerView`)

`ViewHolder1`

`Adapter1`

`Layout1` for row design.

All work well, insert data in adapter and show on `RecyclerView`. But now I need to open a `PopupWindow` from `MainActivity` (on clicking over a  `ImageView`). Inside this inflated layout I need to put another `RecyclerView` to show some other data (different from first data).

So I have another adapter (e.g. `Adapter2`) and another `ViewHolder` (i.e. `ViewHolder2`). How can I manage the `RecyclerView` inside the `PopupWindow` layout? Is only a layout, don't have an `Activity` for manage the `RecyclerView` (like `Fragment1`)? How can I fix this thing?

Obviously, I don't want to stop the `MainActivity` thread.

Comment: I would like to recommend you `DialogActivity` instead of a popup window.

Comment: And yes, `RecyclerView` can be managed from `Fragment` too.

Comment: perfect, work! but why you suggest to use DialogActivity than popupwindows?

Comment: Its just easier to manage.

Comment: Even better, you can use a `DialogFragment`.